# Morph two objects, but the targeted one doesn't fill up entirely

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

[Filelink]
[1](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive)I'm trying to morph that torus to this ring, when I apply the shrinkwrap modifier works perfect but the target object (torus) dont fill up entirely.

How can i resolve this morph problem?

[image: shrinkwrap ring]
[image: torus]
[image: object unfill]

Comment: how shall we know and be able to help you if you show us none of your settings and how you did it? pls provide blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx

Comment: thanks Chris for your interest, i will upload

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive

Comment: sorry, but your link doesn't work